# Sendmail script gives no error , but not getting mail

Tags: sendmail

Below is my simple Sendmail script. while running, it executes without any error .. but not getting any mails in my gmail inbox.

```
#!/bin/bash
SUBJECT="TESTING"
EMAIL="myaddressk@gmail.com"
EMAILMESSAGE="/tmp/emailmessage.txt"
echo "This is a test mail"> $EMAILMESSAGE
# send an email using /bin/mail
/usr/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < $EMAILMESSAGE
```

Comment: What's in the log (e.g. `/var/log/mail`)?

Comment: In my system "/var/log/mail" is a directory and inside that directory there is a file named 'statistics', but which is a data file  
# file  /var/log/mail/statistics 
/var/log/mail/statistics: data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which sendmail do you use? did you configure it correctly? I once used postfix and had a hard time to set it up in an intranet, but I think for your purpose it should not be too hard

look here for more information: http://www.postfix.org/mailq.1.html

Comment: My operating system is Ubuntu 11.04 .. [ Which sendmail means ?] .. I am new to this .. so correct me if I am wrong

Comment: try to reconfigure your sendmail; these pages will help you: https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/postfix.html ; http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/sendmailconfig.8.html ; if it won't work after that, check /var/log/syslog and /var/log/mail.*

Comment: The funny thing is the above Sendmail script worked me for few hours ,, Later I don't know what happened ..  I don't done any major modifications ..

Answer (score 1):

My requirement was to send mail alerts to SVN users on repository modifications .
At last I managed to do it with ssmtp .. steps given below [may be useful for someone]

1. Installed ssmtp
2. Modified file `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` as givne below

   AuthUser=@gmail.com
   AuthPass=
   FromLineOverride=YES
   mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
   UseSTARTTLS=YES

3.Disabled sendmail:

```
# service sendmail stop
# chkconfig sendmail off
# mkdir /root/.bakup
# mv /usr/sbin/sendmail /root/.bakup
# ln -s /usr/sbin/ssmtp /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

4.Testing done

```
$ echo "This is a test" | mail -s "Test" xyz@gmail.com
```

For more details [READ](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-use-gmail-as-a-smarthost.html)

Thanking ShiDoiSi & Hachi for helped me in this to dig more ..